# Apply independent transparent color overlay to material

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency

I'm new to Blender, not sure if this is possible: I want to create a material that has a base color, plus a black overlay with alpha=25%. The goal is to be able to manipulate the base color of the material independently of the overlaid 25% alpha black effect.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do - one face on the top surface is assigned this custom material that overlays the black alpha 25%. Later I might want to change the entire cube to be purple, but that material would still apply the black alpha 25% on top.

I know I could just directly assign the blended color as the base color of a new material, but it will be annoying to do this on a large scale for my project.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple color mix node, set as multiply, should do the trick you need: you can freely set a new color in the green color 1 input color wheel, still there will be 25% of black multiplied on it.

[image]